# Workaround for overflow:hidden; child exception?

Tags: css

I want to show a close button outside of .preview and .shortcut, which both have the attribute overflow: hidden. position: absolute doesn't work and I don't know how how to work around this, since the parent divs resize dynamically.

Any help would be appreciated

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12598822/close_revert.html

```css
.shortcut {
  overflow: hidden;
  /*border: 1px solid blue;*/
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.preview {
  width: 90%;
  height: 75%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  /*-webkit-border-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(white), to(black));
        */
  position: relative;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  /*-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.15);*/
}
```

```html
<div class="shortcut" id="3">
  <div class="preview thumbs">
    <a class="cross" id="crosshidden" href="#"></a>
    <a class="link" href="http://master.elementaryos.org/developer">
      <img class="thumb" src="http://image.thum.io/get/http://www.google.com/" title="Google">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="title">Google</div>
</div>
```

Comment: please post the relevant code here to keep the question valuable

Comment: If the close button is a child of the `overflow: hidden` element and is outside of the dimensions of the button it won't be visible. And it can't be, because of `overflow: hidden`. It's not optionally-applied.

Comment: Yes, I got that from a few other questions. But how could I put the .cross element outside of .shortcut and still have it at the same position as before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could not work but the markup+css you provided doesn't create the layout of yor dropbox page. Anyway to fix it, try following

1) remove `overflow: hidden` from `div.shortcut` and `.preview` classes
2) add following rule to your CSS

```
.preview a{
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

### Update

Not related to this issue but you also want to make `background` style of your `.cross` rule to following (no repeating for background)

```
    background: url("http://www.lngbahrain.com/uploadedImages/EventRedesign/Dubai/2013/January/21276001/Assets/lightbox_close_button.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent
```

Comment: I needed to add .preview a img, then the button shows outside the .shortcut, but is still cut off at the top

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
<div class="shortcut" id="3">
    <div class="preview thumbs">
        <div class="whatever_class" style="height: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
            <a class="link" href="http://master.elementaryos.org/developer">
                <img class="thumb" src="http://api.webthumbnail.org?width=500&height=499&format=png&screen=1024&url=dribbble.com" title="Developer | elementary OS">
            </a>
        </div>
        <a class="cross" id="crosshidden" href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="title">Dribbble</div>
</div>
```

Then, remove `overflow: hidden` from your `.shortcut`, and `.preview` classes.

Just make sure the div I have set as `class="whatever_class"` gets the `style` that I've placed in them. Just a quick solution.